# Delete Facebook profile for a business page account

Tags: facebook-pages

I have a page for my business. I accidentally created a profile for it through the page. I want to delete the profile. Can someone please tell me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, once you have created a profile on a business page it turns in to a personal page.  This action cannot be reverted.

From [this article on the Facebook Help Centre](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12830):

> **What happens if I click the 'Create Your Profile' button at the top of my
>   business account?**
>
> If you click on the "Create Your
>   Profile" button, you will be asked to
>   provide additional information to
>   allow you to transform your business
>   account into a personal account. You
>   will be required to enter your full
>   name, a security question, and an
>   answer to your security question. Once
>   this final registration step is
>   completed, these changes cannot be
>   reverted. You will then permanently
>   have a personal account on the site.

[And from this article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12831)

> **If I turn my business account into a user profile, can that action be
>   reverted?**
>
> No, once you provide the final
>   registration information for creating
>   a user profile, you cannot revert back
>   to your business account.
>
> If you convert your business account
>   into a user profile, you will still be
>   able to manage all the Pages and
>   Facebook Ads you’ve created by
>   clicking the Ads and Pages link in the
>   left hand navigation menu entitled
>   'Applications'. The fans of your Pages
>   will not have visibility or access to
>   your personal profile. Any actions
>   that you take as a Page administrator
>   on your Page will show the Page’s name
>   as the actor and not your personal
>   name. However, if you wish to restrict
>   your privacy so that other Facebook
>   members cannot find you in search or
>   add you as a friend, you can do so by
>   clicking on "privacy" at the top any
>   Facebook page.