# How do I delete a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I wanted to create a page on Facebook, but accidentally created two pages with the same name.

Now, I obviously don't need both pages, so I would like to remove one of them.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/delete-facebook-profile-for-a-buisness-page-account

Comment: @Chris That question is different. The user created a profile for a page, and he wants to delete that profile, but not the page.

Comment: Ah - I wasn't sure, I should have added a question mark somewhere in there though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the facebook page you wish to delete and click on "Edit Page" in the upper left-hand corner under the page avatar.

[image]

Then click "Manage Permissions" once again in the upper left-hand corner.

[image]

Select "Permanently Delete this Page" directly above the "Save Changes" button at the bottom of the page.

[image]

BOOM! Done.

Comment: Thank you Sir :) (under Manage permissions? Stupid Facebook... :) )